# C# Error Message "'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'transaction'" string

Tags: c#, json, ssis

I am using an API to extract data into SQL table using C# code but I am getting an error.

my c# code

```
   var data = dynJson.transactionsList;

            // If response is not null continue to iteratethrough items
            if (ResponseCode == "0")
            {
                foreach (var item in data[0])
                {
                    OutputBuffer.AddRow();
                   OutputBuffer.transaction = Convert.ToString(item.transaction);
                    OutputBuffer.transactionType = Convert.ToString(item.transactionType);
                    OutputBuffer.amount = Convert.ToString(item.amount);
                    OutputBuffer.date = Convert.ToString(item.date);


                }

                offset = offset + 100;
```

My json is :

```
data = {[
  {
    "transaction": "54226",
    "transactionType": "Purchase",
    "Date": "2023-02-01 00:19:50.0",
    "status": "Active",
  },
  {
    "transaction": "232130962",
    "transactionType": "Purchase",
    "Date": "2023-01-25 00:00:00.0",
    "status": "Active",
  },
  {
    "transaction": "32154299",
    "transactionType": "Purchase",
    "Date": "2023-02-01 01:31:05.0",
    "status": "Active",
  }]}
```

I am getting this error:
Message "'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JProperty' does not contain a definition for 'transaction'" string

I do not what is wronf here.

Extract data from API in Json format to insert in sql table using SSIS and C# script

Comment: Your json is not valid.Pls post the valid one. And where is dynJson defined? Pls post the full code

Comment: @Serge what do you mean? This is what I got from variable in visual studio.

Comment: Make sure the code you provide is valid

Answer (score 0):

you can replace  data[0] by data, but it is NEVER good idea to use dynamic, escpecially to deserialize a json string

```
 foreach (var item in data)
                {
                    OutputBuffer.AddRow();
                   OutputBuffer.transaction = item.transaction.ToString();
                    OutputBuffer.transactionType = item.transactionType.ToString();
                    OutputBuffer.amount = Convert.ToString(item.amount);
                    OutputBuffer.date = Convert.ToString(item.date);


                }
```